# [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js, vue-router

Trying to post data to a collection (using Vue (2.6.11), Vuetify (2.4.0), Vuex (3.6.2), Vue-router (3.5.1), Axios) but getting this error. Haven't been able to fix it, not sure why it won't work.

The add item form (AddItem.vue):

```
                <v-form ref="form" v-model="valid">
                    <v-text-field name="title" v-model="form.title" label="title" required>
                    </v-text-field>

                    <v-text-field name="description" v-model="form.description" label="Item Description" required>
                    </v-text-field>

                    <v-select name="categoryID" v-model="form.category" :items="categories" item-text="name" item-value="_id" label="Category" required>
                    </v-select>

                    <v-select name="qualityID" v-model="form.quality" :items="qualities" item-text="name" item-value="_id" label="Quality" required>
                    </v-select>

                    <v-text-field name="price" v-model="form.price" label="Price" required>
                    </v-text-field>

                    <v-file-input name="photo" v-model="form.photo" multiple label="Item photo(s)">
                    </v-file-input>

                    <v-btn rounded text :disabled="!valid" @click="addItem()">
                                Add
                            </v-btn>

                    <v-btn @click="reset">
                        Reset Form
                    </v-btn>
                </v-form>

<script>
    import GoBack from '@/components/GoBack'

    export default {
        name: "addItem",
        data: () => ({
            form: {
                title: "",
                description: "",
                category: "",
                quality: "",
                price: ""
            },
            categories: [
                { _id: "620a6acaff3f5cebc8370121", name: 'Food' },
                { _id: "620a6ae3ff3f5cebc8370123", name: 'Clothes' },
                { _id: "620a6af1ff3f5cebc8370125", name: 'Furniture' },
                { _id: "620a6b04ff3f5cebc8370127", name: 'Electronics' },
                { _id: "620a7a0fded499a220f386d1", name: 'Tools' },
                { _id: "620a7ca7178dada11844dbad", name: 'Toys' }
            ],
        }),
        methods: {
            addItem() {
                if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
                    this.$store.dispatch('addItem', this.form)
                }
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

The store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from '@/config'
import router from '@/router'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  
  actions: {
    addItem() {
      axios
        .post(`/items`, {
          title: this.form.title,
          description: this.form.description,
          categoryID: this.form.category,
          qualityID: this.form.quality,
          price: this.form.price
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
          console.log(error.response.data.message)
          router.push('/items').catch(() => {});
        })
    }
  }
})
```

The errors:

[image: error messages]

The 'title' from the error is specifically referencing 'title' from 'this.store.title' (For example, if I change it to 'this.store.title1' the error will start referencing 'title1'), thought I don't see what's wrong with it, and can't find any solutions. If anyone knows how I can sort this out I'd greatly appreciate it, let me know if there's any more information I can provide, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your store you are trying to use this.form which is undefined. Instead of using this.form you have to use a parameter. You are already passing a parameter to your action here  `this.$store.dispatch('addItem', this.form)` so on this side there is nothing more to do, but you are not using it.

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from '@/config'
import router from '@/router'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  
  actions: {
    addItem({},form) {
      axios
        .post(`/items`, {
          title: form.title,
          description: form.description,
          categoryID: form.category,
          qualityID: form.quality,
          price: form.price
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
          console.log(error.response.data.message)
          router.push('/items').catch(() => {});
        })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried your recommended changes, but it's giving me warnings in the code editor. It says that '{}' is an unexpected empty object pattern, and that 'form' is declared but the value is never read. It also doesn't run in browser giving the errors: 'unexpected empty object pattern' and ''from' is defined but never used'

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I didn't remove the 'this.' from the post fields. It is now successfully attempting to post to the database, but I've got some other error that's preventing an item from actually being added that I need to look in to

Comment: For some reason, the information from the form is not reaching the post request. It won't let me post because some fields like title and description are required, but if I remove the required tags in the backend it posts to the collection, but without any of the info from the form, creating just an empty item with only an _id field

Comment: Could you take a look at your browsers development tools and check if the browsers send the correct body? This way we could identify if the problem is in the frontend or in the backend.

Comment: If I go to network, and payload, I see an empty body as the payload. Is that what you were looking for? I'm almost certain it's a problem with the frontend, everything works perfectly if I used a REST client to access the backend

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, the ````{},```` before form in the addItem action still produces an error in the editor, it says 'Unexpected empty object pattern. eslint(no-empty-pattern)'

Comment: I left it there because when writing actions you normally want to use parts of the context (the first parameter). So there is a question I have. Why are you writing an action in the vuex store when you aren't using the store at all?

Comment: That is a good question, I don't have a good answer for you unfortunately. I'm working in a group project on this and we don't seem to be on the exact same wavelength when it comes to how the project is setup. This is the first time I'm using Vuex, and I'm a bit unfamiliar with it. I just moved the addItem action from store.js to a method in addItem.vue (with a couple of changes), and it is now working perfectly fine. I'm not sure if it was in store.js for a future implementation or something, but we'll cross that bridge if we come to it I suppose. Thank you so much for all your help with this